# ¿Qué significa %02X $((0x${MAC_ADDRESS:13:1} + 1)) en bash usando printf?

Tags: bash, shell, printf

Estoy tratando de entender este código al 100% pero no lo tengo del todo claro, sobre todo por el `printf %02X`:

```sh
MAC_ADDRESS="AF:BA:44:2A:8F:3C"
# Se que sacamos un dijito a la derecha de la posicion '13' con ${MAC_ADDRESS:13:1}
printf %02X $((0x${MAC_ADDRESS:13:1} + 1))
#output:
10
```

Sé que se está permitiendo la suma de números hexadecimales, pero no sé que es lo que lo permite ni el propósito de `%02X` como primer argumento para el comando `printf`.

```sh
# Algo raro es que al querer sumar "1 + D" me da un resultado erroneo, pues el resultado real deberia ser "0E"
printf %02X $((0x1+D))
#output:
01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Dividamos todo lo que sucede para `printf` en tres partes:

- %02X da formato de salida a dos dígitos hexadecimales.
- ((expresión)) todo lo que está allí dentro se evalúa como una expresión aritmética.
- ${cadena:pos:caracteres} extrae *n* caracteres de la subcadena desde *pos* y lo anexa a **0x**

Por lo tanto vas a tener `printf %02X $((0xF+1))`, que en hexa es **10**

---

Respecto de tu duda al hacer `$((0x1+D))`, estás sumando la letra **D** al **0x1** (hexadecimal).

Quizás quisiste hacer lo siguiente `$((0xD+1))`

Espero que te sirva, ¡saludos!

Comment: Ya vi que para sumar 2 hexadecimales debo anteponer `0x` a cualquier numero hexadecimal por ejemplo `$((0x1+D))` sumo la letra D como dices pero yo lo que queria hacer era `$((0x1+0xD))`, pero por alguna razon los numeros decimales se pueden sumar con los hexadecimales siendo de distinto tipo, pero en la expresion aritmetica ambos se evaluan como hexadecimales y por eso es que `$((0xD+1))` funciona, aunque me parece mas limpio especificar ambos con `0x`

Comment: ¿Crees que puedas explicar detalladamente lo del %02X?, es lo que mas quiero entender, el por que de cada dijito, para aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Lo que decís es correcto. Siempre es mejor hacer esto `0x01 + 0x03 - 0x0D`. El caso es que hexadecimal tanto como octal, binario o decimal, es solo un formato de representación numérico conveniente. En neto, siguen siendo números. Por eso podés sumar 1 a 0xD y es igual a `0x1+0xD`, en este caso porque 0x01 = 1. Pero por ejemplo,  `0x0C+0x03` es lo mismo que `12+3` y el resultado es **15 = 0x0F**. El punto es en qué formato ves representado el mismo número. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Si, es fácil. El __%__ es el _operador de formato_ (leete la ayuda de printf), __02__ es la cantidad de dígitos con los que querés ver representada la salida (proba de ponerle %06X y vas a entender, te mostrará la salida con 6 dígitos) y __X__ es el formato numérico (la base) en la cual querés que lo represente (probá de poner %03D y te va a mostrar el mismo número pero en base 10, o sea, decimal y con 3 dígitos)

Comment: Un placer. No tengo telegram, pero hacé tus consultas por acá, ya que así todo lo que resolvemos juntos le sirve a mucha más gente. Saludos!